# Inverse of the product of three particular elements in a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of the identity element $1$ and $a, b, c \in G$.

Show that $(abc)^{-1} = abc \implies  (bca)^{-1}=bca$

I have this that $xy$ becomes $xy$

$e$ becomes $1$

$x^r$ becomes $x^{-1}$

Is this the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really understand your approach.

In any case, you need to check that $(bca)(bca)  = 1$ given that $(abc)(abc) = 1$.

To this end you'll need to "play" with $(bca)(bca)$ a bit.

Let $x =(bca)(bca)$. You want to show, $x=1$. Now $ax = a(bca)(bca) = (abc)(abc)a$, using associative law. And you know  $(abc)(abc)=1$, so 
$ax= 1a = a$. Thus you get $ax = a$. Multiplying by $a^{-1}$ on the left you get $a^{-1}(ax)  =a^{-1}a$ that is $x = 1$, as desired. (You could also say you 'cancel' $a$, but that you are allowed to cancel may not be to be taken for granted at that level.)